# PHP, mysql SELECT statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, vs-web-site-project

I am new to PHP and am unsure as to the syntax of mysql in php. I am trying to check a username from a data_table with the help of the following SELECT statement but seem to be encountering a syntax error. I would really appreciate any help in this matter.

```
$myquery = sprintf("SELECT `Username` FROM `dataTable` WHERE `Username` = \\%s", mysqli->real_escape_string($loginID));

 $userNameCheck = mysqli->query($myquery); 

 if($userNameCheck)
 {
    echo "query succeeded";
 }
```

Comment: can you print the result of `$myquery`?

Comment: Is `$loginID` a string? It must be single-quoted.

Comment: You need to add quotes around the %s for username, and I am also unsure what those \\'s are doing there.

Comment: $loginID is a php variable that holds a string

Comment: Remove the backslashes and substitute `'%s'`

Comment: I read in the php manual that \\ is how u escape a string literal.

Comment: @user1009091 Micheal is asking if the data type of `Username` in your table is a string.

Comment: @user1009091 The `%s` will never be passed into MySQL.  It is a sprintf() placeholder, and should not be escaped.

Comment: "*I'm unsure as to the syntax of MySQL in PHP*". SQL is standard irrelevant to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saw that you are missing the $ sign at mysqli, don't know if that is a typo here or in your code.

```
$myquery = "SELECT `Username` FROM `dataTable` WHERE `Username` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($loginID)."'";
$userNameCheck = $mysqli->query($myquery);
```

And then test what @Ray wrote

Answer (score 3):

Skip the sprintf.

```
  $myquery = "SELECT `Username` FROM `dataTable` WHERE `Username` = '".mysqli->real_escape_string($loginID)."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need quotes, even with your... unusual method of query building. Also, I'm not sure what the double-backslash is in aid of.

```
$myquery = sprintf("..... `Username` = '%s'",mysqli...);
```